# Error when deleting rows from DataTable : "There is no row at position X."

Tags: vb.net, datatable, runtime-error, row

I'm getting the following runtime error when trying to delete rows from a datatable `dt`:

> *There is no row at position 24.
>
>   There is no row at position 20.*

Here's the code (line 3 causes the error):

```
For i As Integer = dt.Rows.Count -1 To 0 Step -1    
    For Each num As Integer In numsArray
   -->  If dt.Rows(i).Item("number") = num Then
            dt.Rows(i).Delete()
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Using a `Try-Catch` block I found that whenever the error occurs the value of index variable `i` equals `dt.Rows.Count`, which is probably the reason for the error. However, it's unclear to me how `i`can even assume this value, since I'm looping from `dt.Rows.Count` **`-1`**.
Any idea what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're iterating over a row collection that you're deleting from; its like sawing through a ladder that you're standing on.

Try this code:

```
For Each num As Integer In numsArray
    For i As Integer = dt.Rows.Count -1 To 0 Step -1    
        If dt.Rows(i).Item("number") = num Then
            dt.Rows(i).Delete()
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are deleting rows and you are continuing with the bucle:

```
For i As Integer = dt.Rows.Count -1 To 0 Step -1    
    For Each num As Integer In numsArray
       If dt.Rows(i).Item("number") = num Then
            dt.Rows(i).Delete()  
            Exit For ' You need to stop looking for a number in this row
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Thanks very much, you hit the nail on the head! ;)